# How to trim specific character from the front and back of a string in excel formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I want to trim '-' from the front and back of a string, not in the middle. So:

```
    -Some-thing- = Some-thing
    -Another = Another
    Some-thing = Some-thing
    One more- = One more
    etc.
```

Does the TRIM function let you do this?

Comment: Is it always only one hyphen or could it be `--teststring` = `teststring` or `-teststring-` = `teststring`?

Answer (score 1):

If it's always just a single hyphen that is hanging out at the end OR the beginning of the word then you could do this with some `if()` functionality:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1, 1) = "-", RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-1), IF(RIGHT(A1, 1)="-", LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-1)))
```

If there is going to by multiple hyphens that need to be removed, I think your best bet is with a UDF:

```
Function TrimCharacter(inString As String, trimChar As String) As String
    For Each word In Split(inString, trimChar)
        If Len(word) > 0 Then TrimCharacter = TrimCharacter & IIf(TrimCharacter = "", word, trimChar & word)
    Next word
End Function
```

Just plop that into a new module in VBE, save your workbook, then you can use it in a cell formula like:

```
=TrimCharacter(A1, "-")
```

And it will trim all hyphens from the beginning and ending of the word.